# How to stop terminal from getting mouse click input?

Tags: mouse, xinput, terminal-multiplexer, pseudoterminal

I was just reading this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4f75u5/how_does_htop_gets_my_mouse_input_via_ssh/) where I found a curious terminal control escape sequence: "\033[?1000h". Naturally, I've tried it to see what could happens. In accordance with the inspiring comment, my terminal started to show chars corresponding to mouse clicks! (Amazing!)

**Questions: 1** The "entity"  mainly responsible for this (terminal showing mouse clicks code) is the line discipline, right?  who caughts the sequence and configure the terminal line for this behavior. In this case, normally does it receive mouse inputs and ignore it or does it "subscribe" itself to acess such information?

**Questions: 2** Is it possible to get mouse coordinates in a equivalent form? How?

**Questions: 3** How do I turn it off!? (closing and opening a new terminal deeply dishonors me!)

Thanks in advanced.

I'am using Debian 9, Xterm.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it off in much the same way that you turned it on:

> **`printf`** [`"\033\[?1000h"`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-1-0-0-0.1F78)

(on) and

> **`printf`** [`"\033\[?1000l"`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-l:Ps-=-1-0-0-0.1F7C)

(off).  See [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

Comment: Thank you! (about the link) Searching for sequences, the sequence "1000h" nor "1000l" haven't matched.

Comment: The links in the answer work.  In the html (and plaintext), literal characters for control sequences are separated by blanks.  In the pdf (or postscript, etc), those are depicted by boxed/outlined characters.  See the [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) for an overview with the different formats.